# How to apply Gradient filter to an Icon?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to put a gradient on my `Icon`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a ShaderMask widget. If you wrap an icon with this, you can apply any gradient you like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: LinearGradientMask(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.book,
              size: 250,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LinearGradientMask extends StatelessWidget {
  LinearGradientMask({this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (bounds) {
        return RadialGradient(
          center: Alignment.topLeft,
          radius: 1,
          colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red],
          tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
        ).createShader(bounds);
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

giving you something like looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It worked for me, but when I change the position of my icon the gradient changes a bit, what is the start point of reference of the ShaderMask? Isn't it supposed to be the same gradient doesn't matter where the icon is?

Comment: Nice catch! I looked into it, and found that there's a bug in the Flutter sdk causing the mask to be incorrectly offset, causing it to change depending on its location onscreen. I submitted a PR (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/45654) to fix it. hopefully

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            child: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.yellow, Colors.black])),
          ),
```

[image]